# Chain operations after several elements have been retrieved

Tags: node.js, intern, leadfoot

For testing we have to fill a complex page using intern/leadfoot. Each part of the page is taken care off by a separate function which receives the necessary elements and input data.

Now we have the problem, that actions on these elements in the subfunctions can not be chained anymore, since they are elements and not commands.

Is it somehow possible to again chain the operations? I tried a lot with creating a new command using `setContext()` or with custom commands but did not succeed so far.

```
let inputs;
return this.remote
  .get('some/url')
  .findAllByTagName('input') // Finds two input elements
  .then(inputElements=> inputs = inputElements)
  .then(()=> Promise.all([
      inputs[0].clearValue(), // I would like to be able to write: inputs[0].clearValue().type('a')
      inputs[1].clearValue(),
  ]))
  .then(()=> Promise.all([
      inputs[0].type('a'),
      inputs[1].type('b'),
  ]))
```

Comment: It might be helpful to provide just a short description of your code so that users don't have to parse through your code to determine the needed action just to be able to determine if they can think of another way to write the solution.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt: just edided the question, is the problem now more comprehensive?

Comment: I'm still just not sure exactly what you are wanting to do. You want to merge your last two then() functions? Is there a reason not to follow the methods described in examples (find, clear, type, end(), find, clear, type end()), maybe with more specific selectors than just tag name?

Comment: After a command has settled and I have got elements, how can I get back to "command behaviour", especially chain operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements share many of the same methods as Commands, but they have different APIs. A primary difference is that Command methods representing actions return Commands (a Command is promise-like, and resolves when the action finishes), but Element methods representing actions do not return Elements (an Element is not promise-like). This means that you can't directly chain many Element methods.

For the situation described in the question, you could do something like the following:

```
function clearAndType(input, value) {
    return remote.then(function (_, setContext) {
            // setContext is always the last argument to a Command then()
            // callback; the value returned by the previous Command is the
            // first argument, which is ignored here
            setContext(input);
        })
        .clearValue()
        .type(value);
}

var remote = this.remote;

return this.remote
    .get('some/url')
    .findAllByTagName('input')
    .then(function (inputs) {
        return Promise.all([
            clearAndType(inputs[0], 'a'),
            clearAndType(inputs[1], 'b'),
            // ...
        ]);
    })
```